# Is it possible to create a UIViewController which is inspectable in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

It's easy to create an IBInspectable / IBDesignable UIView to create a customizable UI component. But is it possible to do so for UIViewController like what Apple did for **UITableViewController, UITabBarController, UINavigationController** so that I can create reusable UIViewController?

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think till now Apple has anything like that as IBInspectable / IBDesignable is only property for UIView